# Puzzled: mysqli query halts script but no error messages

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

The following code does not produce any errors when run, but doesn't work either.

If I replace the query in the server code section with an `echo "8";` placeholder it will return it fine and show up the way I want in the html file at the bottom. But PHP execution stops at the `$mysqli->query()` in the first file listed. I've tried running the query in MySQL workbench and it works fine. PHP doesn't give me any errors. Stumped...

Here is my server code. (db_connect.php)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function dbConnect() {
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "my_db");

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        die ("ERROR: There was an error connecting to the db: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    return $mysqli;
}

function getHealth() {
    $mysqli = dbConnect();

    if($mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM player where name='testname';")) {
        printf("This will return the player health here.");
    }
    else {
        printf("query failure: %s", $mysqli->error));
    }

    $mysqli->close();
}
?>
```

Here is my calling code: (getdata.php)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$requestType = $_GET['req']; // TODO: NOT SECURE

require "db_connect.php";

switch($requestType) {
    case "health":
        echo getHealth();
    break;

    default:
        die ("request not recognized");
}

?>
```

Here is where the ajax request is being made: (`ajaxexample.html`)

```
<html>

<head>
<script>

var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
     document.write("User Health is: " + xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
}

function retrieveUserInfo(requestString) {
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?req=" + requestString, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

retrieveUserInfo('health');

</script>
</head>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked your server error log? It's possible `display_errors` is off, and no matter what you set `error_reporting` to, they will not be outputted.

Comment: Your function `getHealth()` does not return a string, and thus will not have anything to `echo`.  `Mysqli::query()` returns a result resource, but you are testing it inside an `if()`, so you also have no means to fetch its rows.

Comment: BTW, there's nothing inherently insecure about using `$_GET['req']` as you are.  You appear to be correctly whitelisting its possible values in a `switch`, so you're probably ok there.